# Eclipse C/C++ Formatter Line Wrapping or Indentation Problem When a Macro is a Function Parameter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indentation, stm32, formatter

I am having problem when I try to format C code in Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0. When a macro is a parameter of a function, line wrapping doesn't work. It is a bug or I couldn't find the correct setting in Formatter.

```
#define GPIO_PIN_7                 ((uint16_t)0x0080U)

    GPIO_InitAsOutput(&LED_D, GPIOC,
    GPIO_PIN_7,
                      GPIO_OutputType_PushPull, GPIO_Pull_None,
                      GPIO_Speed_Low);
```

In the code above, GPIO_PIN_7 is the problem here. Line wrapping width is 80. When I press "CTRL+SHIFT+F", It should be look like this:

```
PIO_InitAsOutput(&LED_D, GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7,
                 GPIO_OutputType_PushPull, GPIO_Pull_None,
                 GPIO_Speed_Low);
```

However, It doesn't change the format.

One other odd thing is that If I replace GPIO_PIN_7 with ((uint16_t)0x0080U), It is working and code becomes like below:

```
PIO_InitAsOutput(&LED_D, GPIOC, ((uint16_t)0x0080U),
                 GPIO_OutputType_PushPull, GPIO_Pull_None,
                 GPIO_Speed_Low);
```

What should I do to correct this behavior?

Comment: I would suggest using an external formatter (like [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) which can be used via a plugin like [CppStyle](http://www.cppstyle.com/)). CDT's built-in formatter is unmaintained and fairly buggy, especially when it comes to macros.

Comment: I couldn't install CppStyle because it is not compatible with Eclipse version in Atollic TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.3.0. Is there a way to install it, if it is not compatible?

Comment: I was able to install CppStyle in Atollic by using the "Install from update site" installation method, using the `http://www.cppstyle.com/mars` update site.

Answer (score 1):

You just hit the Eclipse bug [459301](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=459301). Until it's fixed you can just use formatter tags if you can use Eclipse 2019-03 with CDT 9.7.

```
//@formatter:off
PIO_InitAsOutput(&LED_D, GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_OutputType_PushPull,
                                GPIO_Pull_None, GPIO_Speed_Low);
//@formatter:on
```